# Is it possible to step into an IronPython dll compiled with pyc?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, ironpython

I am running a .NET 3.5 C# project in Visual Studio 2008. In the project I am hosting an IronPython script that imports modules that I have compiled to .NET dlls with pyc. The version of IronPython is 2.6.1. I have used ObjectOperations.GetInstance and GetMember to wire up the python methods to the C# code.

When I am debugging the C# code and try to step into the pyc generated IronPython dll, VS won't allow me to do that. Is there any way for me to be able to step into that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this out of the box.  You'd need to modify IronPython/DLR so that the calls from ClrModule.CompileToMethod down would pass an option to emit symbols and then ultimately call LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod to emit symbols.